# Stuck on Ubuntu Flash screen

Tags: 18.04

I have successfully installed Ubuntu and was firing it up when it just got stuck on the splash screen. It looked like it was loading forever. I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: if nothing helps i'd suggest to reset your uefi/bios to default factory settings ruling out any misconfigurations (backup current!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me also and was fixed by adding nomodeset to the boot options. After that I installed the GPU drivers and it booted properly from the next time.

Comment: How do you add it to the boot options?

Comment: when your pc boots up and grub starts, press e when ubuntu is selected and type nomodeset before quite splash and press ctrl+X to start ubuntu from there